# Walking Multidimensional arrays in Mawk

Tags: awk, mawk

I'm able to do this properly in gawk, but when I tried to post my code to the machine where it will run, I realized it was using mawk...

```
$ cat multidim.gawk
# test of multidimensional arrays
// {
        A[1][1]="A11"
        A[1][2]="A12"
        A[2][1]="A21"
        A[2][2]="A22"

        i=2
        for ( j in A[i] )
        {
                print "i=" i " j=" j " A[i][j]=" A[i][j]
        }
}


$ echo hi | awk -f multidim.gawk
i=2 j=1 A[i][j]=A21
i=2 j=2 A[i][j]=A22
```

seems mawk has a different idea about how multidimensional arrays should work.  When I run it on Debian with mawk, I get a syntax error.  A[i,j] seems the correct syntax, and it 'synthesizes' multidimensional arrays.

So I tried two things, neither work:

```
$ cat multidim.mawk
// {
        A[1,1]="A11"
        A[1,2]="A12"
        A[2,1]="A21"
        A[2,2]="A22"

        i=2
        for ( j in A[i] )
        {
                print "i=" i " j=" j "a[i,j]=" a[i,j]
        }
}

$ echo hi | awk -f multidim.mawk 
awk: multidim.mawk: line 9: syntax error at or near [
```

Seems sensible, using a 1dim array index on a "multidimensional" array generates an error.

Trying to just walk the WHOLE array so that I can use an if statement to selct the first dimension even (extremely inefficient and horrible)... but I can't even do that!:

```
$ cat multidim2.mawk
# test of multidimensional arrays
// { 
    A[1,1]="A11"    
    A[1,2]="A12"    
    A[2,1]="A21"    
    A[2,2]="A22"    

    for ( (i, j) in A )
    {
        print "i=" i " j=" j "a[i,j]=" a[i,j]
    }
}
$ echo hi | awk -f multidim2.mawk 
awk: multidim2.mawk: line 8: syntax error at or near )
```

Is there any way to walk a multidimensional array in mawk?

Is there a language reference other than the mawk manpage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mawk` (and `nawk`) provide only *synthesised multi-dimensional arrays*.

`gawk` provides (since 4.0, thx *manatwork*) true multi-dimensional arrays, <strike>though the man page (IMHO) misdirects a little: immediately after introducing `if ((i,j) in array)` it follows with "*The in construct may also be used in a for loop to iterate over all the elements of an array.*"</strike> (fixed since v4.1.1!).

But, `for ((i,j) in array)` is not the way to iterate over these, the `gawk` way is (as you used originally):

```
 for (i in array)
     for (j in array[i])
         print array[i][j]
```

With `nawk`/`mawk` you are stuck with *synthesised multi-dimensional arrays*, so

```
for (ij in A) {
    split(ij,xx,SUBSEP);
    printf("A[%s,%s]=%s\n",xx[1],xx[2],A[ij])
}
```

Now, your next problem is going to be *ordering*, array indexes are implicitly string type, and arrays are implicitly unordered. Unless you have separate knowledge of the indexes, as would be the case with a simple non-sparse array with consecutive integer indexes from 0..N. `gawk` offers [a solution for an ordered `in`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html).

If you know the indexes of a synthesised array, then you can use `A[i,j]` (which is treated as `A[i SUBSEP j]`), or `for`/`in` and some string splitting to rebuild the list of `i` and `j`, or `if ((i,j) in A)` (test for presence, without *autovivification* of indexes).

In `gawk` you cannot use `(i,j) in arr` where arr is a true multi-dimensional array, you need to break it into two (or however many dimensions) `for` loops as above. To be fully correct though, the inner loop(s) should contain an `isarray()` condition, since it's not required that every element of `arr[i]` in turn be an array, gawk is happy to allow scalars too.

I know of no `mawk` specific documentation other than [the man page](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html), it aims to be a standard new `awk` (i.e. `nawk`) implementation (so no true multi-dimensional arrays, no index sorting, and no `isarray()`).

Comment: Maybe a small improvement: “`gawk` provides true multi-dimensional arrays _since version 4.0.0_”.

Comment: I was leaving out the question about ordering to keep this question short.  You answered both questions even though I only asked one :-)

Comment: It looks like the lack of multidimensionality is going to cause such a performance and complexity issue, that I'm going to have to shift over to Perl or Python.  Unfortunatley, I can't address this by installing gawk.

Comment: `isarray()` is Gawk only