# Getting sum of values in a field based on variables in other field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to know the sum of values in a field for every variable in another field.
For example for the following input I want to know the sum of values in 3rd column for every value in 1st column:

```
a x 3
b y 4
a y 2
b x 5
```

The output should be:

```
a 5
b 9
```

My data is in `tsv` format. I might want something like this:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{SUM=0}{ SUM+=$3 }END{print SUM}'
```

but for every value of column 1. I found a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484370/how-to-get-sum-of-values-in-column-based-on-variables-in-other-column-separately) here  but as I am very new to awk scripting I am not able to modify the given awk script for my purpose.

I don't have datamash installed so I need a solution with awk and for loop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array indexed on $1.

```
awk -F'\t' '{ SUM[$1] += $3 } END { for (j in SUM) print j, SUM[j] }'
```

Comment: If sequence matters, add ` | sort` to the awk command.

Comment: I know the OP did but - don't use all upper case for user-defined variable names to avoid clashing with builtin variable names (and make it more obvious you're using user-defined instead of builtin variables).

Comment: @edmorton. Agreed not good practice, but decided to show the parallel with the one-variable solution.